# DELETE request, react + flux + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs-flux

I want to create a simple twitter_clone. Now I'm trying to add a feature to be able to unfollow a user. 
What I've done until now:

User can follow other user (I did it through Flux pattern)
I've done it this way:

```
followUser(userId){
    $.post("/followers", {user_id: userId})
    .success(rawFollower => ServerActions.receivedOneFollower(rawFollower))
    .error(error => console.log(error));
},
```

It sends a POST to `/followers` and a USER STORE is fetching this data to update itself.

Now I'm looking for the way how to delete it. I've tried to do it by:

```
unfollowUser(userId){
    console.log ("API.unfollowUser");   
    $.delete("/followers", {user_id: userId})
    .success(unfollowUser => ServerActions.removedOneFollower(unfollowUser))
    .error(error => console.log(error));
}
```

but it doesn't work. I've received an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.delete is not a function

Basically, I try to remove one row from database and accordingly json connected with it and Later to update a STORE (delete this json from array which I use to determine a state of React Element)

This is destroy action from Rails followers controller:

```
def destroy
    follower = Follower.find(user_id: params[:user_id],
                            followed_by: current_user.id)
    follower.destroy    
end
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, the error you're getting is a Javascript error, not a Rails error.

There's no `$.delete` method for jQuery. Instead, you have to use the `$.ajax` one and specify the HTTP method, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/followers',
  method: 'DELETE',
  data: { user_id: userId }
}).done(unfollowUser => ServerActions.removedOneFollower(unfollowUser))
  .fail(error => console.log(error))
```

However, this might also fail because jQuery may not support sending data with a DELETE request, and that makes sense.

If you're using Rails and trying to be RESTful, you shouldn't be sending a DELETE request like this:

```
DELETE /followers
{ user_id: userId }
```

Rather, you should send a DELETE request like this:

```
DELETE /followers/:user_id
```

So to modify the code, it becomes like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/followers/' + userId ,
  method: 'DELETE',
}).done(unfollowUser => ServerActions.removedOneFollower(unfollowUser))
  .fail(error => console.log(error))
```

I haven't tried any of the code above, but It Should Just Work (TM).